# Send the active tab info from background.js to the pop-up (window)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send the currrent active tab information to a pop-up page from the background script but am getting "undefined" when doing so.

Background script:

```
//load popup.html in a pop-up window.

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

    chrome.windows.create({'url': 'HTML/popup.html', 'type': 'popup'}, 
    function(window) {
    });


});

 //return current active tab
 function backgroundFunction () {
    var tab = "";
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    tab = tabs[0].title;
  });
  return tab;
 }
```

popup.js:

```
(function () {
var otherWindows = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
console.log(otherWindows.backgroundFunction()); 
})();
```

My Manifest file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Application Test",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Test Application",
"icons": {
    "128": "icons/icon128.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "16": "icons/icon16.png"
},
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab"

]
}
```

I suspect it is undefined because the background script tab is now "undefined" because of the pop-up window.

How can I sucessfully send the tab info for whatever URL the user was on to the popup.js file when they click the Extension icon?

Comment: Chrome API is asynchronous, see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: Where is your index page defined? `"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "idle.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }`

Comment: I thought if I am using chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener in the background script, I shouldn't use the "default_popup" attribute no?

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome.runtime`, most methods are deprecated in `chrome.extension`

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(backgroundWindow => {
  console.log(backgroundWindow.backgroundFunction());
});
```

Comment: Using this code still does not achieve my task. The console output is blank (because it is probably reading the tab title of the pop-up window) and not the tab title of the URL the user was on before they clicked on the extension icon

Comment: remove all `chrome` stuff from the background script and post your manifest.json